# extbase restoring deleted object fails

Tags: controller, typo3, extbase

A deleted object (deleteAction) can not be restored (restoreAction), brings up a exception:

> Exception while property mapping at property path "": Object with identity "1" not found.

Controller:

```
/**
 * action delete
 *
 * @param \EXAPOINT\Exacallmanagement\Domain\Model\Calls $calls
 * @return void
 */
public function deleteAction(\EXAPOINT\Exacallmanagement\Domain\Model\Calls $calls) {
    $this->callsRepository->remove($calls);
    $this->flashMessageContainer->add('Call gelöscht.');
    $this->redirect('list');
}


/**
 * action restore
 *
 * @param \EXAPOINT\Exacallmanagement\Domain\Model\Calls $calls
 * @return void
 */
public function restoreAction(\EXAPOINT\Exacallmanagement\Domain\Model\Calls $calls) {
    $calls->setDeleted(0);
    $this->callsRepository->update($calls);
    $this->redirect('list');
}
```

Model:

```
/**
 * @var \integer
 */
protected $deleted;

/**
 * @return integer $deleted
 */
public function getDeleted() {
    return $this->deleted;
}

/**
 * @param integer $deleted
 * @return void
 */
public function setDeleted($deleted) {
    $this->deleted = $deleted;
}
```

Does the source of the problem is the fact that a deleted object is not "seen" by the repository? What would be the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property mapper cant handle a deleted object, just pass the uid to your restoreAction and then

- Check if a deletedObject with that ID exists
- If thats the case, restore it
- If not, redirect, flashMessage, whatever you like

Make sure you have the deleted field configured in your TCA:

```
'deleted' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'deleted',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'check',
    ),
),
```

You dont have to add it to any type, but if I remember correctly the field itself must be configured like this.

Comment: do you mean to pass {callUid:calls.uid} to the controller as an integer and then get the call to restore by findByUid?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Comment: okey... strange behavior, the setName works but setDeleted(0) not, any idea?`code` /**
  * action restore
  *
  * @param integer $callUid
  * @return void
  */
 public function restoreAction($callUid) {
  $calls = $this->callsRepository->findByUid($callUid);
  $calls->setDeleted(0);
   $calls->setName('test');
   $this->callsRepository->update($calls);
   $this->redirect('list');
 }

Comment: Have you set it in your tca config?

Comment: set what? Sound like a new chance for me :)

Comment: Your TCA configuration for your table (usually found in my_ext/Configuration/TCA/my_table.php). I updated my answer with the code.

Comment: thank you. this was a help and as a kind of a workaround it works, the post of lorenz (below) seems to bring some help in near future.

Answer (score 1):

The repository has to be configured to find entities that are normally ignored because of the enableFields. In your repository, try something like:

```
public function initializeObject() {
    $defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->get('Tx_Extbase_Persistence_Typo3QuerySettings');
    $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectEnableFields(FALSE);
    $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);
}
```

Comment: When i add you suggestion plus $defaultQuerySettings->setIncludeDeleted(TRUE); then i also see records which are "deleted=1" so the initializeObject() "works" but still got the same Exception while property mapping at property path "":Object with identity "1" not found

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answer: This problem is well known and this is about to change for TYPO3 6.2. You can follow the issue and test an Extbase patch [here](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/55861).

Comment: I just tried the new AbstractController mentioned in forge but id did not helped. Did you used it already?